# Trouble dynamically changing state of checkbox with AJAX

Tags: ajax, checkbox, label

I am trying to have to check boxes through ajax, but it is not working properly. I am not able to **change state of the first checkbox**, only the second one is working fine. Could anyone spot the error here?

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"../scripts/domainlist.php?dept="+deptid+"&pro="+proid,
    contentType:"application/json; charset:utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
        $('#domainlist').empty();
        $('#domainlist')
        .append("<tr rowspan='2' class='domainname'>
                      <th class='domainname'>Domain Name</th>
                      <th class='domainname'>Is this domain applicable to your organization?</th>
                      <th style='height:30px' class='domainname'>Do you want this domain to be displayed?</th>
                 </tr>");
        var index = 0;
        $.each(data,function(i,item){

            var index2=index+1;

            var display_status = "";
            var applicable_status = "";
            if(data[i].applicable == 1){
                applicable_status = "checked";
            }
            if(data[i].display == 1){
                display_status = "checked";
            }

            $('#domainlist')
        .append("<tr class='domainname'>
                    <td class='domainname'>
                       <a href='setcategoryapplicability.php?dom="+ data[i].domid +"'>"+ data[i].domname +"</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <input id='toggle-"+index+"' name='applicable["+data[i].domid+"]' class='toggle toggle-round' type=checkbox "+applicable_status+">
                             <label for='toggle-"+index+"]'></label>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                        <input id='toggle-"+index2+"' name='display["+data[i].domid+"]' class='toggle toggle-round' type=checkbox "+display_status+">
                             <label for='toggle-"+index2+"'></label>
                 </td>
               </tr>");
            index = index +2;
        });
    },
    complete: function(){
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: what are you getting in `applicable_status`??
can you try `console.log(applicable_status)` and what is output of this?

Comment: applicable_status is working fine. It could be 1 or 0. If 1, I want the checkbox to be checked, else not.

Comment: Also, the out put is coming fine. The issue is I am not able to check/ uncheck the check boxes in 'Is this domain applicable to your organization?' column, while I am able to change the check boxes in the last column. I don't understand why?

Comment: does `applicable_status` comes `1` at **Is this domain applicable to your organization?** Because you code seems good, not any error in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so sorry to trouble you guys. I feel so stupid. Thank you for your responses. It is working fine now.
[image]

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

### Confirm your data is correct

If your data is coming in as expected, the application should work.

If you are having trouble with the first checkbox, then `data[i].applicable` may not be in the expected format.

See the example below where I pass in hard coded data in the expected format (based on my reading of the code since you didn't provide an example data object):

```js
var data = [
    {
        "domid": "domid_A",
        "domname": "Domain Name A",
        "applicable": 0,
        "display": 0
    },
    {
        "domid": "domid_B",
        "domname": "Domain Name B",
        "applicable": 1,
        "display": 1
    }
];
var index = 0;

$('#domainlist').empty();
$('#domainlist').append(
    "<tr rowspan='2' class='domainname'>" +
    "    <th class='domainname'>Domain Name</th>" +
    "    <th class='domainname'>Is this domain applicable to your organization?</th>" + 
    "    <th style='height:30px' class='domainname'>Do you want this domain to be displayed?</th>" +
    "</tr>"
);
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    
    var index2 = index + 1;
    var display_status = "";
    var applicable_status = "";

    if (data[i].applicable == 1) {
        applicable_status = "checked";
    }

    if (data[i].display == 1) {
        display_status = "checked";
    }
    
    $('#domainlist').append(
        "<tr class='domainname'>" +
        "    <td class='domainname'>" +
        "        <a href='setcategoryapplicability.php?dom=" + data[i].domid + "'>" + data[i].domname + "</a>" +
        "    </td>" +
        "    <td>" +
        "        <input id='toggle-" + index + "' name='applicable[" + data[i].domid + "]' class='toggle toggle-round' type=checkbox " + applicable_status + ">" +
        "        <label for='toggle-" + index + "]'></label>" + 
        "    </td>" +
        "    <td>" +
        "        <input id='toggle-" + index2 + "' name='display[" + data[i].domid + "]' class='toggle toggle-round' type=checkbox " + display_status + ">" +
        "        <label for='toggle-" + index2 + "'></label>" +
        "    </td>" +
        "</tr>"
    );
    index = index + 2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="domainlist"></table>
```

Comment: Data is coming just fine. Infact, the checkboxes are checked and unchecked as in the database, the issue is with using label and checkbox in the second column. check boxes in the third column are also working fine.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are having with labels. Can you clarify?

Comment: If I click on the labels in column 2 of the table, it won't change the state. If it is on, it will stay on, and if it is off, it will stay off. While the labels in the column3 are working just fine. I don't understand this behavior.